# How can you implement Lua into your game?

Tags: c++, architecture, lua

I am trying to implement Lua into my game, but am having trouble. Say I have a weapon class, which is just a hollow shell, lacking real functions. I was thinking of creating an onFire function, which will simply call a pointer to a Lua function that was created for that weapon. Is this the way most people do it? Are there any other ways?

Comment: This question is really too open-ended. You need to, at the very least, explain in some detail about what you want scripts to control and do in your game.

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed call Lua functions from C++ code, you'd just need to import a Lua header and compile against Lua libraries

This site offers great examples:
[Using Lua with C++](http://csl.name/lua/)

Comment: A much better site and tutorial can be found here: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/the-lua-tutorial-r2999